# Let $g : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by the equation $g(x,y)=(2ye^{2x},xe^y)$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be given

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $g : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $$g(x,y)=(2ye^{2x},xe^y).$$ Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $$f(x,y)=(3x-y^2, 2x+y, xy+y^3).$$

(a) Show that there is a neighborhood of $(0,1)$ that $g$ carries in a one-to-one fashion onto a neighborhood of $(2,0)$.

(b) Find $D(f\circ g^{-1})$ at $(2,0)$.

For (a), I will use the inverse function theorem, I must prove that $Dg(0,1)$ is non-singular, we know that $$Dg(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}4ye^{2x} & 2e^{2x}\\ e^y & xe^y\end{bmatrix},$$ so $$Dg(0,1)=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 2\\ e & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\det Dg(0,1)=-2e\neq 0,$$ we conclude then, by the inverse function theorem that there is a neighborhood of $(0,1)$ that $g$ carries in a one-to-one fashion onto a neighborhood of $g(0,1)=(2,0)$.

(b) $$D(f\circ g^{-1}(t))=Df(g^{-1}(t))[Dg(h(t))]^{-1}=Df(h(t))[Dg(h(t))]^{-1},$$where $h$ is the inverse function of $g$, how can I calculate $h(2,0)$?

Are these arguments right? Thank you very much.

**This problem is the "analysis on manifolds" by Munkres**

Comment: Please state where you found this problem.

Comment: @edm              This problem is the "analysis on manifolds" by Munkres

Comment: Not in this comment section. State it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for (a) is correct and I've got nothing to comment on it (except maybe that the determinant is $-2e$ instead of $2e$, whatever).

For (b), you do  $${\sf D}(f\circ g^{-1})(2,0) = {\sf D}f(g^{-1}(2,0))\circ  {\sf D}g^{-1}(2,0) = {\sf D}f(0,1) \circ  {\sf D}g(0,1)^{-1}. $$

You compute ${\sf D}f(0,1)$ directly like in (a), and you invert the result of (a) to obtain ${\sf D}g(0,1)^{-1}$. This all holds in the neighbourhood given by the Inverse Function Theorem.